# Ensure 2 methods succeed else roll back

Tags: c#, transactionscope

Can anyone please tell me whether this is possible.

I have some code that allows a user to upload/change their image, before the change takes place I delete the default/old image from disk before uploading new image.

Problem is if something goes wrong either with the delete or upload, how can I roll back both so that the original image is returned.

I thought I could use tranactionscope, but either I'm not using it correctly or it not applicable for this case.

All the examples I have found involve using 2 call to database, but my code only involves one call and that's to update.

```
//TODO check transactionscope works ok
using (var tran = new TransactionScope())
{
    //Delete old image before updating new image
    //123 bogus number to throw error
    var deleteOldImage = _igmpfu.DisplayProfileDetailsForUpdate("123")
                                .FirstOrDefault();

    if (Convert.ToString(deleteOldImage) != 
        "5bb188f0-2508-4cbd-b83d-9a5fe5914a1b.png")
    {
        DeleteOldImage(deleteOldImage);
    }

    //Insert new image
    var imageGuid = imageId + ".png";
    bool imageUrl = _iuma.UpdateAvatar(cookieId, imageGuid);

    if (imageUrl)
    {
        TempData["Message"] = "Image updated";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Members");
    }
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Any assistance in helping a newbie would be appreciated

//------------------------

I have been looking at the computer to long, all I had to do was

```
var deleteOldImage = _igmpfu.DisplayProfileDetailsForUpdate("123").FirstOrDefault();
                        if (deleteOldImage != null)
                        {

                           code here for writing to disk
                        }
```

I have spent ages trying to work this out and thats all I had to do :-(

Thanks everyone for their replies.

Comment: If one of your 2 calls to the database failed, then the transaction won't complete, it will only persist to the database once the tran.complete is called, thus it will rollback automatically. I think you are in the right track.

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks, but the problem I have is its still saves the uploaded image to disk, which is not what I want

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis - the TransactionScope is worthless unless every class being called inside it knows how to participate in the transaction which I doubt whatever `_igmpfu` and `_iuma` are do.

Comment: What is _igmpfu, and _iuma? ADO.NET or EF? Either way, try passing the transaction to them.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis - you don't pass transactions around, the classes need to understand how to enlist in a transaction if there is an active one.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have would only work if the classes you are using know how to enlist in the transaction.

The main issue you will encounter when dealing with files is that the file system is difficult to deal with transactionally. The approach I would use is this:

1. Save the new file on disk with a different filename.
2. Update the database with the new filename.
3. If the db update was successful, delete the old file from disk, if not delete the new file from disk.

Comment: Hey Trevor, how can you say that dealing with files is that the file system is difficult to deal with transactionally? Aren't they just bytes?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis what I mean is that there are no classes in `System.IO` which can participate in a `Transaction` to undo whatever action you have taken upon rollback.

Comment: as far as I know you should store your file into bytes, so you don't want to save the entire image as a file to database, no? I would like to hear your opinion

Comment: Sorted problem out been looking at computer to long